Why is language switch leading to a non-associated page?
If you switch from German to Polish on homepage here in hamburger menu, the page switches to /kontakt. Same for the other way round, it goes to /de/kontakt.

The language association in menu configuration is correct.
All other pages lead to correct associated pages.
The page entry is based on some customized contact template, which I assume is causing the problem. Both are also marked as default pages for each language.
The links are wrong in <a> elements themselves, no redirection problem.

Why does that happen? How to prevent it and switch homepage to homepage?
